# Assertion failure leads to iPhone crashing when presenting modal view controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

The error is as follows:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UIWindowController.m:188

When I click a button, it triggers my first `presentModalViewController` from the below function:

```
-(void)go{
    //this second presenting viewcontroller
    SinaWeiBoViewController *sinaviewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sinaweibo"];

    [self presentModalViewController:sinaviewController animated:YES];   
}
```

When this function runs, the second view is presented and a crash occurs. The demo code is downloadable [here](http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/read.php?tid=95947).

Answer (score 0):

I am too get this error. And case in

```
self
```

value. Try set here another UIViewController class